# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following Traceback Error for my function:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Here's my code:

```
def age():
    thirties_df = (df.loc[df['age'] <= 39]) & (df.loc[df['age'] >= 30])
    fourties_df = (df.loc[df['age'] <= 49]) & (df.loc[df['age'] >= 40])
    fifties_df = (df.loc[df['age'] <= 59]) & (df.loc[df['age'] >= 50])
    sixties_df = (df.loc[df['age'] <= 69]) & (df.loc[df['age'] >= 60])
    seventies_df = (df.loc[df['age'] <= 79]) & (df.loc[df['age'] >= 70])
    eighties_df = (df.loc[df['age'] <= 89]) & (df.loc[df['age'] >= 80])
    for i in thirties_df, fourties_df, fifties_df, sixties_df, 
    \ seventies_df, eighties_df:
```

Comment: I don't know pandas, but you may have to move your parentheses a little.

Answer (score 0):

The error is regarding the use of suspicious '&' character that you used in instantiating those variables.('&' between those two strings mean nothing but produces error)

Also there is no meaning to put `and` (i think you were trying to put this)
between strings because the last assignment is used as the value of that variable.
See this:-

```
>>> var = 'str1' and 'str2'
>>> var
'str2'
```

Comment: thanks for the response. the reason for the '&' sign was to indicate a condition where df['age'] was both above AND below the given range. if you are saying this isnt doing what i want, do you know a better way for me to do it?

Comment: @bullybear17 what is df here?

Comment: df is a csv i imported with multiple columns like 'state', 'gender', 'race', 'age. I indexed the csv with the person's name. With this particular function, i want to return any values between x & y for the column 'age'. so for example, thirties_df would be a variable where I can store all information JUST for people in the csv who are between ages 30 & 39

Comment: @bullybear17 Well i haven't read about csv till now; but i am pretty sure that a single variable can't store two values at same time. But you can try to store that range in a sequence like list or tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without `df`, but it looks like your age column are strings. And the parenthesis are misplaced: `df['age'] <= 39` is a Series of dtype bool. And the & of 2 Series of bool is itself a Series of bool, which you can use to do a selection on a DataFrame <sup><sub>*(if it has the right length)*</sub></sup>

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    map(str, np.random.randint(5, 90, size=1000)),
    columns=('age',)
)  # what I think your df roughly looks like.
df['age'] = df['age'].astype('int')  # make sure age is numeric
# building thirties_df step by step
younger_than_forty = df['age'] <= 39
older_than_thirty = df['age'] >= 30
thirties_df = df[younger_than_forty & older_than_thirty]
# or all at once and using loc like in your question
thirties_df = df.loc[(df['age'] <= 39) & (df['age'] >= 30)]
# or using between
thirties_df = df[df['age'].between(30, 39)]

# because
assert all(df['age'].between(30, 39) == younger_than_forty & older_than_thirty)

# so age could become something like
def age(df):
    min_age = 30
    max_age = 80
    buckets = (
        df[df["age"].between(n, n + 9)]
        for n in range(min_age, max_age + 1, 10)
    )
    for i in buckets:
        print(i)
```